# Angular JS: Calculate Difference between two times for each row using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie to AngularJS.I am just trying to subtract the times between two columns and saved the result into third column of each row using ng-repeat.
Expected Output:

```
9:00   10:30   90(in minutes)
```

HTML:

```
<table id="t1" style="border:none;">
    <tr><th>Start</th><th>Stop</th><th>Downtime(In Min)</th><th>Reason</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in invoice.items">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.start"></td>
    <td><input  type="text" ng-model="item.stop" ng-blur="diff()" ></td>
    <td><input  type="text" ng-bind="item.down" ></td>
    <td style="border:none;"><a href ng-click="remove(item)">X</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border:none;">
    <td style="border:none;"><a href ng-click="add()">+</a></td>
  </tr>
    </table>
```

AngularJS:

```
var mapp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
mapp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
 $scope.diff=function(){
                $scope.item.down=$scope.item.stop-$scope.item.start }
});
```

I unable to get the ng-model values from ng-repeat into controller.Whenever I will add the  rows that function should be called.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't simply do math on those strings .. `"10:30"-"9:00"` returns `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**Note:** *This answer is based on assumption that time is accepted in 24hr format.*

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/U3pVM/23452/)

```js
function testCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.diff = "";
  $scope.$watch("startTime", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.diff = computeDiff(newValue, $scope.endTime);
  });
  $scope.$watch("endTime", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.diff = computeDiff($scope.startTime, newValue);
  });

  function computeDiff(startTime, endTime) {
    if (startTime && endTime) {
      var s_hr = startTime.split(":")[0] || 0;
      var s_min = startTime.split(":")[1] || 0;
      var e_hr = endTime.split(":")[0] || 0;
      var e_min = endTime.split(":")[1] || 0;

      return Math.abs((parseInt(e_hr) - parseInt(s_hr)) * 60) + Math.abs(parseInt(e_min) - parseInt(s_min))
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="startTime">
    <input type="text" ng-model="endTime">
    <input type="text" ng-model="diff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/U3pVM/23456/) using `ng-blur` and `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Moving in right direction but try using `1:00` and `12:00`.

Comment: Well I started with assumption of 24hr format. but even this can be handled. I'll update my answer

Comment: Right...would need clarification

Comment: it has to be 24hr format, since OP is not having `am` or `pm` in question.

Comment: @rajesh. Thanks for your reply.One Doubt, You have any idea how to used  those values of ng-model into controller.Like for eg.$scope.item.start=9:00 and $scope.item.stop=10:30 using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to why you want to use `ngBlur` for this? Instead just change:

```
<td><input  type="text" ng-bind="item.down" ></td>
```

to

```
<td><input  type="text" ng-init="diff(item)">{{item.down}}</td>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.diff = function(item) {
    item.down = convertToDateTime(item.stop) - convertToDateTime(item.start);
}
```

Here, `convertToDateTime` is a function that converts the input string to a date(but doesn't modify it!) and returns the timestamp. Since, you haven't specified the format of string so I leave the 'extracting date from the string' part to you.

Comment: `ng-bind` is not for form controls, `ng-init` should not be used this way per docs and the math won't work with time strings

Comment: @charlietfl, the question here is not the math but subtraction of the two values. Its about why the function isn't being called.

Comment: No...did you try it? The html isn't even what OP is expecting. Why are you using `ng-init` against recommendations in documentation?

Comment: @TarunDugar.Thanks for your reply.But its still not working.